# when or from where

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

The figure rose until 2012 when it experienced a significant fall.

The figure rose until 2012 from where it experienced a significant fall.

Which is correct?

Comment: Are you pointing to a chart? If not you're referring only to a "when"  .. a time. If the sentence were talking about points on a chart,  inflection points etc, you could use where.  For example, the tangent (when two lines kiss) or an intersection might be a where. When is probably better even then.

Comment: Either is correct.  The first is a simple time reference.  The second envisions "the figure" in a graph, and "from where" is a point on the graph.  The first should probably have a comma after "2012".  The argument for a comma in the second is a little less well defined.

Comment: Yeah I try to describe a graph.

Comment: Have you considered [whence](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whence)?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to indicate that you are referring to a graph rather than simply describing events in time.

Answer (score 0):

The first is better, but I recommend "The figure rose until 2012 at which time it experienced a significant fall"

Answer (score 0):

'… when it experienced a significant fall' suggests a really steep fall… perhaps even a straight line, as in 'it fell off a cliff'… the total time taken for the fall being very small, because the action takes place *at* the point in time.

'… from where…' suggests something more gradual, starting at 2012 and falling continuously over a longer period, because if the action is measured *from* a point in time, it must end elsewhen.